# Circular progress bar with gradient in background

Tags: html, css

I have the following circular progress bar, the coloring of which is a bit messed up thanks to the background gradient (the white is the progress, the rest of the orange should ideally be identical to the background):
[image: Progress bar]

I made this by using two circles, and two linear gradients on the outer circle whose degrees get generated dynamically based on the progress. The problem stems from having a background color that itself is a gradient. The css I use for this is as follows:

```
html, body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, #e24a00 0%, #f6891f 71%, #fcb732 100%);
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

    .learn-prog {
background-image:
        <% learn_hash = learn_degrees(@my_today_flashcards, current_user.words_per_day) %>
        linear-gradient(<%= learn_hash[:degrees]  %>deg, <%= learn_hash[:color] %> 50%, transparent 50%),
        linear-gradient(-90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

The code that generates the degrees / coloring for learn_hash is here (I had to do it like this because the gradient can't be more than 50%, otherwise it starts going backwards):

```
def color_and_degrees(decimal_completed)
    todo_degrees = todo_degrees(decimal_completed)
    is_over_half = ((todo_degrees/180) > 0 ? true : false)
    if is_over_half
      {:color => 'white', :degrees => (todo_degrees - 180)}
    else
      { :color => 'rgba(246, 137, 31, 1)', :degrees => todo_degrees }
    end
  end

  def todo_degrees(decimal_completed)
    degrees = (360) * (decimal_completed)
    degrees - 90
  end

  def learn_degrees(todays_flashcards, words_per_day)
    #cards_created_today / words_per_day
    if words_per_day == 0
      decimal_completed = 1.0
    else
      decimal_completed = todays_flashcards.size / words_per_day.to_f
      decimal_completed = 1.0 if decimal_completed >= 1.0
    end
    color_and_degrees(decimal_completed)
  end
```

Any ideas on how to make the colors match would be great.
Thanks and cheers,
Michael

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't grasp every bits of your current implementation but could the inner orange gradient be transparent instead? The blue circle should then rely on a circular border...

Comment: I ended up solving this by giving the outer circle a background color of the same orange that gets created by the 2nd gradient. That way, it's consistent between the two gradients, and it looks solid. Given that I solved this, should I delete this question, or should I answer it in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have a transparent gap between your text and that outer blueish circle.
**`radial-gradient()`** allows that ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)).

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/opvPKE)**

Relevant part:

`background-image: radial-gradient(
     closest-side,
     white 90%,
     transparent 90%, transparent 95%,
     slateblue 95%, slateblue 100%);`

`closest-side` is needed because it's a disc. Default for a radial gradient is to have 100% at the corners and they are far out a disc obviously so you wouldn't see the gradient after err 70.7% (half the diagonal = sqrt(2)/2).

I did not add your circular progress bar but I hope it still works nicely with a multibackground :)

Demo:

```css
html, body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, #e24a00 0%, #f6891f 71%, #fcb732 100%);
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

    .learn-prog {
      display: flex; /* centering text */
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
background-image:
        radial-gradient(closest-side, white 90%, transparent 90%, transparent 95%, slateblue 95%, slateblue 100%);
      border: 1px solid #000; /* visualize boundary of elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="learn-prog">HELLO</div>

<div class="learn-prog" style="margin-left: auto">MOVE</div>
```

Comment: Interesting... so how would you go about filling it up, say, 30% around the circle? this definitely seems to be going in the right direction, but the implementation of the progress bar is specifically the part that's throwing me off. I tried playing around with it inside your codepen for the last 30 minutes or so and couldn't get it to work :( Can't even get white to show up. Any push in the right direction for the progress part would help.